# Acer Iconia Tab 10(A3-A40) not booting

Tags: boot, tablet, acer-iconia-tab-10

I deleted the rom and recovery(by mistake) from my tablet(Acer Iconia Tab 10) and at least it booted in a bootloop, now, after 4 hours, the display is not even turning on, I tried to recharge the tablet and when I plug in the USB, the recharging sign shows up on the display.
I cannot even access fastboot or recovery.
Is there something that I can try ? Or its dead.

Comment: Its not dead I reckon, you need to find the original stock firmware and re-install it. Its not dead ( at least you are seeing the recharge sign)

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I have the original firmware, but I don't have a way to re-install it, no fastboot or recovery.

Comment: Shouldn't the system automatically detect firmware file once you insert it in the root of external /internal sd card. I hardly use fastboot commands when reinstalling firmware

Comment: Tell me, if you extract the .zip firmware file what other files are present after extraction?

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/ektd5m) , Screenshot of the folder
@xavier_fakerat

Comment: great, so the intial file was update.zip right?

Answer (score 0):

If your tablet has **Mediatek MT8163A** SoC then all you need is:

- **SP Flash Tool** To download firmware from PC.
- **Stock Firmware** for MT8163A Iconia Tab 10.
- Use **Download Only** to download the missing **system.img** and **recovery.img**